undesired partitions on main disk
When I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my Dell vostro 3480 I wanted to wipe completely the main disk (SSD 256GB) to have only Ubuntu (no more windows at all) but I should have made a mistake, and I have now 10 partitions including one reserved for Windows...
I have now (in this order at disks):

Partition 8 106MB: mounted/empty
Partition 2 17 MB: mounted/empty
Partition 1 1.1GB: mounted/empty
partition 3 2.1GB: mounted/file syst inside (efi/grub, etc)
Partition 6 1.1GB: mounted/empty (format FAT32-Windows reserved)
Partition 9 2.1GB: mounted at boot/empty
Partition 10 205GB: mounted/Ubuntu
Partition 5 43GB:  mounted at /media/root, var, etc.
Partition 4 819MB: mounted at /media/empty
Partition 7 1GB: mounted at /media/empty

I would like to add all those "unused" partitions to other used by Ubuntu to have more room. Please, can anybody give me some tips to solve this problem?

It may be easier to reinstall Ubuntu and create partitions as you want than modifying the partitions. But it will erase everything so you'll have to backup your data first.

You already know the hard part: How to locate and use the disks application.
The rest that you need to know:

You cannot edit mounted partitions
Disks is available on the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment
Re-partitioning is inherently risky. Always backup data before

So your process is:

Backup any data, just in case.
Boot an Ubuntu LiveUSB (instead of your hard drive)
Enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment.
Use Disks to edit the (unmounted) partitions of your hard drive.
Remove the LiveUSB and reboot into your installed Ubuntu.

If something goes terribly wrong, you have a LiveUSB installer and data backup handy.
